# How to Ignore "Cannot add or update a child row" error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have an sql query from my backup files, it has huge amount of insert statements.

> INSERT INTO `tns_spo_hotel` (`id_spo`, `id_hotel`) VALUES
>   (523,149),(523,195), ...

I have a foreign keys on both columns.

When i run this query, it returns

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tsakhkad_tour_new`.`tns_spo_hotel`, CONSTRAINT `tns_spo_hotel_22` FOREIGN KEY (`id_hotel`) REFERENCES `tns_hotel` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Because there are some rows, with missing values.

Is it possible to ignore that error message and continue sql execution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to ignore that error message and continue sql execution
>   ?

Short answer is **No**.

You can't ignore the error and continue with these invalid values. Because thats what the foreign keys constraints do. Thats why they called constraints. They ensure data consistency. If you could ignore these values that violate foreign key reference, your data becomes inconsistent.

The only possible way is to remove the foreign key constraint. But you shouldn't do that, fix your data entry instead.

Comment: ... which you don't want to do.

Comment: I realised! I was just adding something extra to your last sentence, which you've now done yourself :-).